# Can dissolved aluminium from centrifuge tank deactivate enzymes?

Tags: enzymes

I extract an enzyme called diamine oxidase with a [tubular centrifuge](http://www.tomo-e.co.jp/cmsfiles/product/i-7TBem-m.jpg). The centrifuge uses an aluminium tank to collect the liquide after centrifugation. I asked myself what would happen if some aluminium particles pell of from the tank due to the collision of liquid and got into the solution. Could this deactivate the enzyme?